# In what folders or files can services appear and start from

Tags: boot, services

In Ubuntu, what folders or files are used to hold service files that can start at boot time. I know for example `/etc/init.d` is one folder which holds several service files. `/etc/rc.local` is a file that can also boot some services, but what others are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

> ```
> Ubuntu currently employs a hybrid system where core services are handled by 
> Upstart, but additional services can be run in the legacy SystemV mode.
> ```

All upstart [system jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#system-job) by default live in `/etc/init/` while [session job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job) can be found in:

- $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/upstart/ (or $HOME/.config/upstart/ if $XDG_CONFIG_HOME not set).
- $HOME/.init/ (deprecated - supported for legacy User Jobs).
- $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
- /usr/share/upstart/sessions/

Session Jobs are managed by the users own [Session Init](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/Specs/RaringUpstartUserSessions#Desktop_Session_Startup).

SystemV service init script are in `/etc/init.d/` and in `/etc/rcX.d` are present symbolic link to enabled service. `/etc/rc.local` file is executed as last service at the end of each multiuser [runlevel](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/212/An_introduction_to_run-levels).